# Conjectute: no exist an equilateral triangle such that all vertices are integer numbers

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am looking for a solution for a conjecture as follows.

> *In  Cartesian plane, no exist an equilateral triangle such that three vertices are integer numbers.*

I hope that you like the question and let me a answer.

Comment: Are you measuring angles in degrees or radians? If degrees, take an equilateral triangle with side lengths $1$.

Comment: Also the sum of angles must be equal to $\pi$ so of course no all three angles can be rational.

Comment: Thank to Dear Mister @QiaochuYuan , I am sorry, my original equestion in 

https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/AdvancedPlaneGeometry/conversations/messages/3149

Comment: I thank to Dr. @LoïcTeyssier  for your answer , I am sorry, I edited and post my original question in 

https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/AdvancedPlaneGeometry/conversations/messages/3149

Comment: Nice question.  Wrong forum.  It might work for math.stackexchange.  (Also, it has been proved that equilateral triangles embed in Z^3 and not Z^2.) Gerhard "This Is Not Math.StackExchange Forum" Paseman, 2016.03.19.

Comment: This has many nice proofs and generalizations. For example, compare the area formula for equilateral triangle with side $a$ $\sqrt{3}/4 a^2$ and the fact that double area must be integer.

Comment: My favorite proof of this is to observe that if you can do it with an equilateral triangle, then by a few reflections you can do it with a regular hexagon, and then there's a nice visual proof that a regular hexagon cannot be put on the integer lattice: http://mathoverflow.net/a/25305/5701

Comment: @VaughnClimenhaga, can't you just use the same visual proof directly on the equilateral triangle itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let A,B,C be the vertices.Use the fact that the area is $E=\frac{1}{2}\cdot |det(\vec{AB},\vec{AC})|$
Since $det(\vec{AB},\vec{AC})$ is an integer and the area must be of the form
$AB^2\cdot \frac{\sqrt3}{4}$ which is not an integer you can see the contradiction