# proof without words for logarithms

Tags: teaching

Does anyone know of any PROOF WITHOUT WORDS for logarithmic functions?
The only one I've seen in calculus based and I need one for high school math kids in MATH 1,2,3.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi, I think you would be better off at http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There might be something at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some:

http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~liverani/Inform04/Logarithm.pdf (Proof without words: ln(a · b) = ln a + ln b)

http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Ferlini-MaMag-2001.pdf (Proof Without Words: Logarithm of a Number and Its Reciprocal).

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690586 (Proof without Words: The Arithmetic-Logarithmic-Geometric Mean Inequality) reproduced in http://apcentral.collegeboard.com/apc/public/repository/ap08_Nelsen_proofs.pdf (A Sampler of Visual Proofs in First-year Calculus).