# Desargues ten point configuration $D_{10}$ in LaTeX

Tags: graph-theory, euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry, combinatorial-optimization, latex

I want to draw the [Desargues configuration](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DesarguesConfiguration.html) $10_3$ in LaTeX using the standard picture environment, which allows only lines with the slopes $n:m$ where $\max\{|n|,|m|\}\le 6$. Is it possible? If not, then what is the smallest number $s$ for which there exists a drawing of the Desargues configuration $10_3$ in which all lines have slopes $n:m$ with $\max\{|n|,|m|\}\le s$? And for this smallest $s$, what is the smallest number $c$ for which there exists a drawing of the Desargues configuration $10_3$ in which all lines have slopes $n:m$ with $\max\{|n|,|m|\}\le s$ and all points have integer coordinates $(x,y)$ with $\max\{|x|,|y|\}\le c$?

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5pv4.png) image OK?

Comment: Perhaps you'll get more replies on TeX SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AlexRavsky Yes, Sasha, it is perfect: uses only lines with slopes $(n,m)$ where $\max\{|n|,|m|\}\le 2$, which is probably the best possible. And the coordinates are also small. Very good. Please write down this as an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Done...........

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

This example shows that $s\le 2$ and for this $s$, $c\le 3$.
Note that we are lucky with the latter, because there is a [configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perles_configuration) for which every combinatorially equivalent realization has at least one irrational number as one of its coordinates.

Comment: Such a simple and beautiful drawing of the classical Desargue configuration! It is strange that Google does not find it is the Internet...